# Pandas columns became sorted after appending to new dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I would like to append the row(s) that have unique values (excluding empty cells) from `df1` to an empty `df2`.
The structure of `df1` is like this:

```
idx   A1     B1    C1    A2    B2    C2 
---------------------------------------
I1    n      n            b     c 
J1    x      x      x     x     x     x
K1    a      b      c     d     e     f
```

So in this case, row `K1` will be appended to `df2` because all the values are unique.
To append the row, I tried

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = df2.append(df1.loc['K1'],sort=False)
```

I was expecting

```
idx   A1     B1    C1    A2    B2    C2 
---------------------------------------
K1    a      b      c     d     e     f
```

But actually I got

```
idx   A1     A2    B1    B2    C1    C2 
---------------------------------------
K1    a      d      b    e      c     f
```

Looks like the columns were sorted, even I set `sort=False`. I know I can hard code it as

`df2 = df2.append({'idx':idx,'A1':df1.loc[idx,'A1'],'A2':df1.loc[idx,'A2'],'B1':df1.loc[idx,'B1']...})`
to achieve what I want. But my actual file has 30+ columns and it's impossible to hard code every column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `append` a series to a dataframe, so it sorts the columns. Try to append on both dataframe to keep original columns order (note: *`append` defaults `sort` to False, so you don't need specify it*)

```
df_final = df2.append(df1.loc[['K1']])

Out[63]:
    A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2
idx
K1   a  b  c  d  e  f
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do the fix

```
df2 = df2.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
   A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2
K1  a  b  c  d  e  f
```

The `sort = False` in `append` is for row sort